# $\TeX$ in super-collider drop down thing

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

Feature request to get $\TeX$ markup working in the drop down box.  I'm often annoyed by unreadable question titles from `math.stackexchange.com` appearing in there.

[image]

Comment: There are probably many other things you might be using in SE network, where TeX is not rendered.
For example if you use [filters](http://stackexchange.com/filters/) or if you subscribe to the [MSE newsletter](http://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=math.stackexchange.com).
With some basic knowledge of TeX, the titles are readable. In some of these cases, [the bookmarklets for rendering MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/should-chat-have-tex-support/) might help.

Comment: Another way to solve this is to write enough $\TeX$ code so you can see through the code immediately.